# Is there any tool that improves intellisense in vc++ (vs2008)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, intellisense

Is there any free tool that improves Intellisense and provides code snippet in vc++ 2008?
Please don't post commercial tools

Comment: What sort of improvements do you have in mind? Intellisense is quite powerful in VS2008, so chances are that the feature you think of is already in there you just don't know how to invoke it.

Comment: What improvements are you looking for in intellisense ? VS traditionally does a great job with intellisense...

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try Visual Assist - what "feature" are you trying to get in VS intellisense? Otherwise why isn't ProductX like ProductY is a unanswerable question.

Comment: Raising the price up to $250 + $50/year (or $100/year) too expensive?  I think it is crazy that VA is so expensive.  I have had a personal copy for several years.  I am hooked, but I don't know if I can justify the new expense.  Luckily my boss at work is hooked too, so I can at least count on a copy at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not that I am aware of.

Can you explain what you would like to see improved in the intellisense engine?  It's possible some of the behavior you are seeing is a bug that we may be able to help you work around if you can detail what's going on.

Comment: I am missing auto complete should invoke with out pressing ctrl+space at beginning of words and relevance of identifying method name like 'getName()' just by typing 'name'

Answer (score 7):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/)

In my experience the intellisense in VS is excellent, when it works.  Whether through some quirk of how projects are set up, or a bug in VS, I don't know.  But often on larger projects it ceases to work properly.  I have not yet encountered that with Visual Assist.

Comment: I would add that it has additional features, like support for refactoring (renaming, creating method declaration/implementation, etc). Intellisense for file names is also a powerful feature.

Comment: VA is awesome but it isn't free.  IMHO it's worth its price (I just paid my yearly $99 maintenance fee yesterday!)  The refactoring/renaming and improved syntax highlighting are features I use everyday.

Comment: Hmm.  I somehow missed the part about not posting commercial tools.  While VA is obviously a commercial tool, I completely agree with jwfaern, it is well worth the price.